# Which event (javascript / jQuery) fires when a HTTP-Request is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, httprequest

I need this kind of event for the following purpose:

1 considering a standard html-form (no ajax)
2. user submits the form - expecting a pdf 
3.1 request takes a while (> 2min)
3.2 user should see a spinner o.s., while the request is processing
4. spinner should disappear, when download-dialog pops up (need event here)

Comment: Where would you want the spinner to show if the whole page is loading? In an iframe/frame?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no AJAX involved, `$(document).ready(...)`...since the page is reloaded completely (this is standard browser behavior).

Also, if the destination is a PDF, there will be no JavaScript on the other side anyway :)

Comment: @threadstarter - if you're destination after the POST is a PDF...yes, there's no JavaScript involved there.  Standard browser behavior is to leave the previous page, which ends *all* JavaScript operations...if it was AJAX then there are certainly options, but there's nothing to carry over behavior from one page to another except cookies...and then you're talking about a flash inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

You should make an ajax request for this, otherwise it's not really gonna work. You could consider putting the generation in a background job and email the ppl once a request is finished.

Keep in mind that a request that takes that long will in most cases fire a timeout.